# XSLT: Merge two nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to convert below XML through XSLT by groping based on **Email** tag and merge two nodes into one and get all the elements in one node. Please advise

**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Details>  
    <Worker>
        <Name>AAA</Name>
        <Email>AAA@test.com</Email>
        <Item>BBB</Item>
        <Avg_Amount>425.20</Avg_Amount>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <Manager>AAA</Manager>
        <Email>AAA@test.com</Email>
        <Item>BBB</Item>
        <Draft_Amount>1826.64</Draft_Amount>
    </Worker>   
</Details>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.test/bsvc" exclude-result-prefixes="wd">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        
        <Transactions>
            
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Details/Worker" group-by='Email'>
                
                <Manager>             
                    <Name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                    </Name>
                    <Email>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Email"/>
                    </Email>
                    
                    
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="Item">
                        
                        <Worker>
                            <Name>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                            </Name>
                            <Email>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Email"/>
                            </Email>
                            <Item>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Item"/>
                            </Item>
                            
                            <Avg_Amount>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Avg_Amount"/>
                            </Avg_Amount>
                            <Draft_Amount>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Charges_Draft"/>
                            </Draft_Amount>
                            
                            
                        </Worker>
                        
                        
                        
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                    
                </Manager>
                
            </xsl:for-each-group>
            
        </Transactions>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output generated:**

```
<Transactions>
   <Manager>
      <Name>AAA</Name>
      <Email>AAA@test.com</Email>
      <Worker>
         <Name>AAA</Name>
         <Email>AAA@test.com</Email>
         <Item>BBB</Item>
         <Avg_Amount>425.20</Avg_Amount>
         <Draft_Amount/>
      </Worker>
   </Manager>
</Transactions>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<Transactions>
   <Manager>
      <Name>AAA</Name>
      <Email>AAA@test.com</Email>
      <Worker>
         <Name>AAA</Name>
         <Email>AAA@test.com</Email>
         <Item>BBB</Item>
         <Avg_Amount>425.20</Avg_Amount>
         <Draft_Amount>1826.64</Draft_Amount>
      </Worker>
   </Manager>
</Transactions>
```

I would like to convert below XML through XSLT by groping based on **Email** tag and merge two nodes into one and get all the elements in one node. Please advise

Comment: Will Name and Item always be the same between the two elements sharing the same e-mail?

Comment: Change `<xsl:value-of select="Charges_Draft"/>` to `<xsl:value-of select="Draft_Amount"/>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `Draft_Amount` to select `Draft_Amount` from the `current-group()`:

```
<Draft_Amount>
  <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/Draft_Amount"/>
</Draft_Amount>
```

But should consider what you would want to do if there are more than one `Draft_Amount` among multiple `Worker`. You could average them, select the first, etc.

Also, your example data only has one `Avg_Amount` element, but you might consider changing `Avg_Amount` to compute the average of all `Avg_Amount`.

```
<Avg_Amount>
  <xsl:value-of select="avg(current-group()/Avg_Amount)"/>
</Avg_Amount>
```

You could eliminate the extra `xsl:for-each`, and could simplify the code a bit and just copy some of those elements, instead of recreating the element and selecting the values:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.test/bsvc" exclude-result-prefixes="wd">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/"> 
        <Transactions>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Details/Worker" group-by='Email'>     
                <Manager>   
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Name|Email"/>
                    <Worker>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="Name|Email|Item"/>
                        <Avg_Amount>
                            <xsl:value-of select="avg(current-group()/Avg_Amount)"/>
                        </Avg_Amount>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="(current-group()/Draft_Amount)[1]"/>
                    </Worker>
                </Manager>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </Transactions>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```